# Hanging HtmlAgilityPack Task

Tags: c#, winforms, web-crawler, task, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse an html page with HtmlAgilityPack to Extract links from it then add links to ListBox then add the links from listBox to queue.
I have three Tasks(PageParse,AddItemsToList,EnqueueFromList)
**OK My problem is when I click the button the whole Application is hanging.**

*button Code*

```
private void CrawdBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = Task.Factory.StartNew(PageParse);
        t.Wait();
        TaskAddToList = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddItemsToList(t.Result));
        TaskAddToList.Wait();

        b = new Task(EnqueueFromList);
        b.Start();
        //Task.WaitAll(t,b);
        CrawdBtn.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Page Parse Method

```
public HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument PageParse()
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Page Parse Has started");

        web = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc = web.Load(UrlText.Text);



        return doc;
    }
```

Add Items To list code

```
private void AddItemsToList(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode Node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            HtmlAttribute att = Node.Attributes["href"];
            listBox1.Invoke(new AddToListDelegate(AddToList), att.Value);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

### I have Noticed by following breakpoints That the debugger is hanging when it goes to execute PageParse Method

Comment: `Wait()` makes the whole procedure synchronous. (Btw, why `TaskFactory.StartNew()` instead of `Task.Run()`?). You need to make your event handler `async`, then you can call async methods using `Task.Run()` when a native async version of a method is not available. For example, add this to your `Button.Click` async handler: `var doc = await GetDocumentAsync(url);` and add these two methods: `internal HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument GetDocument(string url) => new HtmlWeb().Load(url);` and `internal Task<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument> GetDocumentAsync(string url) => Task.Run(() => GetDocument(url));`

Comment: Of course, you can add those Tasks to a `List<Task<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument>>` and then `var docs = await Task.WhenAll([Your List Of Tasks]);`. `docs` will contain all the HtmlDocument objects. Or modify the async/sync methods to return the already elaborated list of strings/HtmlElements/whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in using async method, use the `PageParse` in Async fashion like this.

```
    public static async Task<HtmlDocument> PageParse(String url)
    {
        return await new HtmlWeb().LoadFromWebAsync(url);
    }
```

You can also get a list of all the href values using Linq then assign / AddRange to AddToList. This will prevent a 1 second delay for "each" of the URLs that are returned from the site.

```
t.Result.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Select(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
```

I am not sure what the third task does but would suggest testing these two tasks in above method to see if it resolves your hanging issues.