# How do I scrape web content async?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, html-agility-pack

Here is what I tried so far. This works but the Form is Freezing everytime it updates

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.roblox.com/catalog/527365852/Dominus-Praefectus");
            foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='item-details']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[2]"))
            {
                textBox1.Text = item.InnerText;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hanging HtmlAgilityPack Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549480/hanging-htmlagilitypack-task)

Comment: Also: [google for HtmlAgilityPack async](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=HtmlAgilityPack+async)

Comment: Where can I Insert the XPath?

Comment: Also note that you're overwriting the text in the textbox with each item found, so effectively only the last item will be displayed.

Comment: The Value on the Website is constantly Updating